# How to handle forward slash in JSON variable with Gson API

Tags: java, gson

I have JSON string that needs to be converted in Java object using Google Gson library.
I am stuck in converting due to forward slash in the following JSON string.

```
{
    "status":"200",
    "results":{
    "resultitems":[
        {
            "uri":"/document/id/e20a8dad50d91a839c50ab5f323f3df3",
            "path":"Data/xyz/abcdata",
            "metadata":{
                "data/category/item":"yahoo/post",
                "ast_id":"67677"
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Indeed, for `Data/category/item`, I am getting a null value. How can I correctly parse it?

Comment: There's nothing special about forward slash in JSON -- it's just a normal character.  Your tools must be buggering it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just a starting note: the JSON you put in request is not a valid JSON, but can be easily fixed adding a brace (I used fixed JSON in my answer).*

I suggest you to parse your JSON this way. Declare the following classes.

---

```
public class Container {

    public int status;
    public Results results;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container [status=" + status + ", results=" + results + "]";
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Results {

    public List<ResultItem> resultitems;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Results [resultitems=" + resultitems + "]";
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ResultItem {

    String uri;
    String path;
    HashMap metadata;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResultItem [uri=" + uri + ", path=" + path + ", metadata="
                + metadata + "]";
    }

}
```

and then call this code:

```
public class Q19684865 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = " {    "                                                                   
                + "     \"status\":\"200\",                                                  "
                + "     \"results\":{                                                        "
                + "     \"resultitems\":[                                                    "
                + "         {                                                                "
                + "             \"uri\":\"/document/id/e20a8dad50d91a839c50ab5f323f3df3\",   "
                + "             \"path\":\"Data/xyz/abcdata\",                               "
                + "             \"metadata\":{                                               "
                + "                 \"data/category/item\":\"yahoo/post\",                   "
                + "                 \"ast_id\":\"67677\"                                     "
                + "            }                                                             "
                + "     }                                                                    "
                + "    ]                                                                     "
                + "   }                                                                      "
                + " }                                                                        ";

        Container c = new Gson().fromJson(json, Container.class);
        System.out.println("this is the parsed json: " +c);
        System.out.println("this is the property 'data/category/item': "+c.results.resultitems.get(0).metadata.get("data/category/item"));

    }
```

and this is the result:

```
this is the parsed json: Container [status=200, results=Results [resultitems=[ResultItem [uri=/document/id/e20a8dad50d91a839c50ab5f323f3df3, path=Data/xyz/abcdata, metadata={data/category/item=yahoo/post, ast_id=67677}]]]]
this is the property 'data/category/item': yahoo/post
```

Explanation: normally you need just POJOs if you do not have particular needs, where POJO field name corresponds to the label of the JSON value. But 'data/category/item' cannot be a valid Java identifier. So I chose to parse to a Map.

A second way could be to replace in JSON string your "data/category/item" with a valid Java identifier, "data_category_item" for example or, if you can change JSON origin, do the same at the source.